# SQL Server: Type conversion in division operation

Tags: sql-server

When i'm trying to use division operation where numerator is decimal(18,2) and denominator is varchar which contrains decimal number with different scale without any conversion it retuns incorrect value.

For example:

```
SELECT 925.16/'3.6678'
```

which returns incorrect result - `252.08719346`

When i tried to use conversion for varchar value:

```
SELECT 925.16/Convert(decimal(18,2),'3.6678')
```

it still returns wrong result -`252.087193460490463215258`

If i convert to float:

```
SELECT 925.16/Convert(float,'3.6678')
```

it will return correct value - `252.238399040297`

Can someone explaine why is there so difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all to do with data precedence. You have an equation with 2 different data types, a `decimal(5,2)` and a `varchar(6)`. The decimal has a higher priority than the varchar, thus the varchar is converted to a `decimal(5,2)`, which is `3.67`. So, the result you got is actually correct:

```
925.16 / 3.67 = 252.087193
```

As for the `CONVERT(decimal(18,2)` why *would* you expect that to be the right result? You're stripping the decimal places, of course it'll be 'wrong".

So, what did we learn? Don't store numbers as a `varchar`. :)